# Reinstall windows and ubuntu dualboot

Tags: windows, ubuntu, installation, multi-boot

I have windows 8 and ubuntu dualbooted. But I ended up with a lot mess on both  sides. Plus I had my motherboard broken and bought a new one. And now when I boot into ubuntu, after some time it just freezes, only mouse is moving.
So I have windows installation cd. Do I need to prepare something before I reboot my computer with windows cd inserted and remove all partitions, when it will be prompted, and just install windows like usual. Can I just install windows the usual way?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can install Windows like normal. Just choose the custom install option and delete all of the partitions.

Also, make sure to back up everything you need from both operating systems. That's all going to disappear.